# Scala closure behavior during exception handling

Tags: scala, exception, closures

I was reading article related to exception handling in Scala and came across this code snippet on [this](http://www.tzavellas.com/techblog/2010/09/20/catching-throwable-in-scala/) blog.

```
def containsEven(nums: String*): Boolean = {
    try {
      for (i <- nums) {
        if (i.toInt % 2 == 0)
          return true
      }
    } catch { case e => () }
    false
  }
```

This code always return *false* as output regardless of input. And this is explanation given on blog.

> From the above implementation we would expect that containsEven("1",
>   "3") should return false and that containsEven("2", "3") should return
>   true. Unfortunately this is not the case and regardless of the input
>   our method always returns false. This is because in the catch block we
>   used a pattern that catches Throwable with the expression case e =>
>   ... instead of the longer but more correct pattern case e:
>   NumberFormatException => ... that only catches NumberFormatException.
>   To understand why this is the cause of the bug we need to understand
>   how Scala implements non-local return from closures.

There more explanation related to

> non-local return

which as a naive Scala programmer I could not digest.

So can someone help me understand what is wrong with closures in this case in simpler words?

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement actually throws, meaning that the next line of execution might not be local. Because `case e` is indiscriminate, it catches all throwables.  Now the `try` and the `catch` have both been completed so execution continues to the next line, `false`, and exits the `def` with that value.

Put this in place and see what you get with various inputs.

```
catch { case e => println(s"caught:$e");() }
```

And this will give you completely different results.

```
catch { case e: NumberFormatException => println(s"caught:$e");() }
```

Comment: I agree with the change you suggested. I had kept `catch { case e =>` for understanding why it is behaving like this.